# cancelling and restarting alarm not working as intended

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have a WakefulIntentService which basically pings the server to check for some data, at some fixed interval.

`WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new PingWakefulListener(), this, false);`

If data is available, I cancel the alarms

`WakefulIntentService.cancelAlarms(getApplicationContext());`

to process the data.

When processing is done I reschedule the alarms

`WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new PingWakefulListener(), AcceptOrder.this, false);`

What I observe is, when force( the third parameter) is false, the alarms are not scheduled again. So, the server is not pinged again.

But, if I set `force` to `true`, two services runs at same time.

What is the correct way of scheduling and cancelling alarms?

I found that, time elapsed after last alarm is less than `getMaxAge`. SO the alarm is not scheduled again. But, cancelling the alarm should have cleared that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like `cancelAlarms()` just removes the `AlarmManager` event and does not update the `SharedPreferences`. That's a [bug](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/issues/11), and I will work on fixing it this weekend.

That being said, I am somewhat nervous about `scheduleAlarms()` in light of the new inexact-by-nature `AlarmManager` behavior on Android 4.4+. Make sure that `getMaxAge()` returns a large enough value to take the inexact-ness into account.